# What would be another way to write this code in mathematica

Tags: project-euler

What would be another way to write this code in mathematica,but without using the code for and if? Is integer digits necessary foor this type of code?

```
b = 0;
For[i = 1, True, i++, b += Boole[BouncyQ[i]];
 If[b/i == 99/100, Break[]]]
i
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the code is expected to do?

Comment: its suppose to follow project Euler problem 112 heree is the link, thank you! 
 https://projecteuler.net/problem=112#:~:text=Working%20from%20left%2Dto%2Dright,number%3B%20for%20example%2C%20134468.&text=Surprisingly%2C%20bouncy%20numbers%20become%20more,numbers%20is%20equal%20to%2090%25.

Comment: my prof doesn't want us to use for and if yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler projects are in general not easily to solve by brute force. Here is a program that does what you want. However, this program would run much too long. Euler projects should be solved by brain not PC:

```
Bouncy[n_] := (LessEqual[##] || GreaterEqual[##]) & @@ 
   IntegerDigits[n];
count = 0; i = 100;
While[count < i 99/100, count += Boole@Bouncy[i++]] ;
count
```

Comment: I believe you're missing a `Not` in your definition of `Bouncy`

Comment: @Joshua Schrier You are right.

Answer (score 2):

If your professor doesn't want you to use For and If yet, s/he may not want you to use advanced functional programming...such as the use of [NestWhile](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html)...but here it goes anyway.

Assuming you have already defined `BouncyQ`,

```
(*evaluates the "next" (n+1) term and how many items are bouncy so far*)

bouncyWrapper[{n_, nBouncy_}] := {n + 1, nBouncy + Boole[BouncyQ[n + 1]]}


(* function that tests whether to stop *)

stopCriterion[threshold_][{n_, nBouncy_}] := (nBouncy/n) != threshold


(* perform the evaluation, stopping when the stopCriterion is True *)
NestWhile[
 bouncyWrapper, (*function to evaluate*)
 {1, 0}, (*initial condition*)
 stopCriterion[50/100] (*function that evaluates the stopping criterion*)
] (* {538, 269}*)

(* another example with 99/100 as the stop threshold *)
NestWhile[
 bouncyWrapper,
 {1, 0},
 stopCriterion[99/100]] (* {1587000, 1571130} *)
```